# MS Teams personal Tabs wont support Classic SharePoint Pages?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

MS Teams' static personal Tabs Apps won't support Classic SharePoint Pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nanda Kumar, Teams do not support Classic version. Only Modern version is supported.